# C++ Accessing bitset<8> two bits at a time

Tags: c++, std-bitset

I have a vector of bitset<8> that looks like this:

`01010110 01010111 01011000` etc..

How can I access the bits two at a time? How can I store two bits in a variable?

For the first element of the vector I want `01`, then `01`, then `01`, then `10` and so on..

Comment: Convert it to a string first then loop over the pairs.

Comment: `std::bitset` supports an [indexing operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/operator_at). For storing you can use a `std::vector<std::bitset<2>>`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 how would you convert it to string? static_cast?

Comment: `bs.to_string()`

Answer (score 0):

One simple way I can imagine is doing this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <bitset>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<std::bitset<8>> vec_b8 {
        std::bitset<8>("01010110"), 
        std::bitset<8>("01010111"), 
        std::bitset<8>("01011000")
    };
    std::vector<std::bitset<2>> vec_b2;

    for(auto b8 : vec_b8) {
        for(size_t i = b8.size() - 2; i > 0; --i) {
            std::bitset<2> b2;
            b2[0] = b8[i];
            b2[1] = b8[i+1];
            vec_b2.emplace_back(b2);        
        }
    }

    for(auto b2 : vec_b2) {
        std::cout << b2.to_string() << " ";
    }
}
```

The output is

> ```
> 01 10 01 10 01 11 01 10 01 10 01 11 01 10 01 11 10 00
> ```

See the [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f0a97ae687d7205c).

Comment: I am getting this error after I tried(added) your code with my file: `malloc: *** error for object 0x100812800: incorrect checksum for freed object - object was probably modified after being freed.
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug`

Comment: @Gus That seems to be an unrelated problem. As you see at the link my code works properly.

Comment: why did you use `b2[0]` and `b2[2]`?

Comment: @Gus A typo, sorry

Comment: @Gus There were some fixes to do.